# centering a <nav> tag horizontally on a web page

Tags: css

I've been trying to get a  tag centered horizontally on my web page, but I'm not having much success.  I have several other elements centered using  tags and they render exactly as they should.  This is probably a simple fix but and if so, it's been staring me right in the face for the past few hours.  Here's the css I'm using:

```
body {
    background-color: #B0C4DE;
     }
h1 {margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 200%;
}


h2 {margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 150%;
}

nav { 
    width: 550px; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
}

nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}

    nav ul li:hover > ul {
        display: block;
    }

nav ul {
    background: #efefef; 
    background: linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);  
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%); 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%,#bbbbbb 100%); 
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    padding: 0 25px;
    border-radius: 35px;  
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-table;
}
    nav ul:after {
        content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
    }

nav ul li {
    float: left;
}
    nav ul li:hover {
        background: #4b545f;
        background: linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%,#5f6975 40%);
    }
        nav ul li:hover a {
            color: #fff;
        }

    nav ul li a {
        display: block; padding: 15px 15px;
        color: #757575; text-decoration: none;
    }

nav ul ul {
    background: #5f6975; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0;
    position: absolute; top: 100%;
}
    nav ul ul li {
        float: none; 
        border-top: 5px solid #6b727c;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
        position: relative;
    }
        nav ul ul li a {
            padding: 5px 3px;
            color: #fff;
        }   
            nav ul ul li a:hover {
                background: #4b545f;
            }

nav ul ul ul {
    position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0;
}

table, td, th {
     border: 1px solid green;
      text-align: center;
    padding: 1px;
}

th {
     background-color: green;
     color: white;
 }
table
{ 
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}


iframe {display: block; /*new*/
        margin: auto;
        border: none; /*revised*/
        width: 800px;
        height: 200px;}

div.center p {text-align: center;
} /*new*/

 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang = "en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystylesheet.css">
    <title>Tech Order Department.html</title>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8" />


<style>

div {
    text-align: justify;
    }


.section {
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     width: 60%;
    }
</style>

</head>

<body>

    <h1>Logistics</h1>
<br>
    <h2>Tech Order Department</h2>

<div class="center">

<nav id=wrap>

<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://www.oldgamer60.com/Project/Home.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.oldgamer60.com/Project/Staff.php">Our Staff</li></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.oldgamer60.com/Project/Projects.php">Projects</a></li>              

    </ul>
</nav>
</nav>

</div>
<br>

<div>

<div class="section">
<p>YAI has been extensively involved in the writing of technical manuals, provisioning and Modification Work Orders (MWOs) for all type of military aviation and ground systems. YAI logistic services have included development and assessment of logistical requirements, preparation of integrated logistic products and field service support  for military aviation, missile and ground combat systems.</>

<p>YAI's Logistic Capabilities include:</p>

<ul>

<li>Technical Manual Writing</li>

<li>Technical Manual Change Pages</li>

<li>Manual Illustrating</li>

<li>MWO Writing</li>

<li>Tagging of Data for Use in Electronic Manuals</li>

<li>Provisioning</li>

<li>Logistical Analyses and Assessments</li>

</ul>

</div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: helps if you also provide some html markup to see where there might be an issue. Use jsfiddle

Comment: Any chance of a working example?

Comment: @VikingBlooded Sorry about that.  I've added the html

Comment: try margin:auto on your div class=center and give it a specific width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<nav>` *is* horizontally centred, it's the `<ul>` inside the `<nav>` which isn't.

This appears to result from:

```
nav ul {
    ...
    display: inline-table;
}
```

Instead, give the `nav ul` element a `width` and declare it as block-level (instead of inline), in addition to specifying `auto` as the value for `margin-left` and `margin-right`:

```
nav ul {
display: block;
margin: 18px auto;
width: 235px;
}
```

Comment: I gave it a shot and it does center the nav bar onto the page; however; the block element remains stationary if I resize the page

Comment: It's working on my browser (Firefox 42). What browser are you using, @Tony?

Comment: I'm using IE 11.  I expanded the block a little to get the ul items to line up horizontally, but otherwise made the suggested changes you provided.

Comment: I've managed to duplicate your error (I think). It comes from `nav { 
    width: 550px; margin: 0 auto;}` - you can replace it with `nav { 
    width: auto; margin: 0 auto;}` - or even simply remove the declaration completely (ie. it's not necessary).

Comment: I think that was it.  I pulled the code from the css and it works great now. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

insert the nav tag in a container div with a specific class.

```
<div class="container">
    <nav> .......</nav>
</div>
```

Then insert a css rule for the class (margin:auto).

```
.container {
  margin:auto;  
}
```

Excuse me for my english :)

Comment: could you post an image of the nav bar and provide source code ? (html and css)

Comment: I edited the original post to put the source code there

Comment: You have a lot of nav ul ul css rules with absolute positioning. maybe this is the mistake. Margin auto does not work with absolute positioning if your element has a fixed width (550px in your case). remove width rule and try to use Left and Right rules with same value in px. This should work